# UITextView offsets text differently than UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I am using *UILabel* and *UITextView* and they render text differently. It seems that *UITextView* offsets text by 4.

Below is an example where at the top is *UILabel* and bellow is *UITextView*. They both use same font. Two examples are here, one with the custom *OpenSans* font and one with the system's *HelveticaNeue* font.

*UILabel* is being resized after setting the text by using *sizeThatFits:*

```
    label.text = text;
    CGFloat width = 320 - 2 * 16; // both label and textView end up with 288 width
    CGSize size = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(16, 0, width, size.height);
    label.frame = frame;
```

*UITextView*.*textContainerInset* is set to (0,0,0,0).

Any help? Here are the screenshots:

***1.1 HelveticaNeue: textView offset -4 (label on top)***
[image: HelveticaNeue: offset -4]

***1.2 HelveticaNeue: aligned (label on top)***
[image: HelveticaNeue - aligned]

***2.1 OpenSans: textView offset -4 (label on top)***
[image: OpenSans - offset -4]

***2.2 OpenSans: aligned (label on top)***
[image: OpenSans - aligned]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This works for me and eliminates the inner padding:

```
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Comment: Thanks, lineFragmentPadding was the key.