# Label in uitextfield left view not aligned with the text

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel, placeholder

I'm making a custom `textField` with a label in his left view but the text of the label is not aligned with the text/placeholder of the `textField`.

Here my simple code:

```
 class mytextfield: UITextField {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        leftViewMode = .always
        let label = UILabel()

        label.text = "Hello"
        leftView = label
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: bounds.height)
    }
}
```

Here the result on simulator (I underlined in red to see the difference) and debug view hierarchy:

[image]

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: I think that the quickest solution would be instead of setting a `UILabel` would be to set a `UITextField` (non-selectable/editable) as the `leftView`. This is an issue with the text container/layout/insets, same as a UITextView doesn't fits exactly a UILabel if we put bot of them aligned in frame.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. To set an UITextField as the leftView of an UITextField ? It seems to be a little bit tricky...

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you mean ! I'm going to try !

Comment: It works ! I think it's a good solution for this issue, Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

This may be issue of rendering with font style or bound size of frame for both views. Try to adjust `y-position` or `height` for left label view.

This's not an exact answer, that you are looking for. But this may solve your problem.

```
override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: (bounds.height - 4))
}
```

or

```
override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: 0, y: -2, width: 40, height: bounds.height)
}
```

---

#### I've tried this:

```
class LeftViewTextfield: UITextField {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        leftViewMode = .always
        let label = UILabel()
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        label.text = "Hello"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        leftView = label
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: -0.5, width: 40, height: bounds.height)
    }
}


class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    var textField: LeftViewTextfield?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupTextField()
    }

    func setupTextField() -> Void {
        textField = LeftViewTextfield(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 100, height: 40))
        textField?.text = "Hello"
        textField?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        textField?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        self.view.addSubview(textField!)
    }

}
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: I just tried and this doesn't work :/ the rects are aligned but not the texts

Comment: I think the Larme's comment is the best adaptable solution.

Comment: After more thinking, your answer is also good for what I want :)

Comment: Did you try with different sizes (font, frames)? Then the inset might change.

Comment: @Larme - Yes, you are right. This answer is just a hint type of solution to OP. He needs to decide, how he can adjust left view according to different font-style and frame. He can setup a function adjusting font style as well for both views.

Answer (score 0):

You do:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Hello"
leftView = label
```

The issue is that the default baselines, insets layouts, text containers of a `UILabel` is not the same as the one by default used for a `UITextField`.

They are not the same between a `UITextView` and a `UILabel` too. Just check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104431/uitextview-offsets-text-differently-than-uilabel) (they are others on SO too). Author superpose a `UITextView` and a `UILabel` and the rendering is different.

Quick way to do so, avoiding repeating the whole internal layout settings of the `UITextField` and replicate it on the `UILabel` is to set the `leftView` as a `UITextField`. Just make it "non-selectable/non-editable" and it should make a perfect illusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
func setLeftIconwithLabel(_ icon: UIImage) {
    
    let padding = 10
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let size = Int(screenWidth*0.04)
    
    let outerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: size) )
    outerView.backgroundColor = .clear
    let iconView  = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: padding, y: 0, width: size, height: size))
    iconView.image = icon
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: iconView.frame.origin.x+iconView.frame.width + 5, y: 0, width: 40, height: 15))
    label.text = "+ 965 "
    label.font = UIFont(name: fontName.ProximaNova_Regular, size: Font.regular12)
    outerView.addSubview(iconView)
    outerView.addSubview(label)
    
    leftView = outerView
    leftViewMode = .always
    
}

txtEmail.setLeftIconwithLabel(UIImage(named: "mobile") ?? UIImage())
txtEmail.placeholder = "Mobile Number"
```